# What is the best route to select a time?

Tags: interaction-design, time, datetimepicker

Firstly, apologies if this has been asked, I did a search and couldn't see anything so here goes.

I have 2 routes I have identified to select an appointment slot to book in with a health practitioner. The slots are set by the practitioners so can't be changed. Context is for mobile.

**Route A**:

[image]

I have this right now, a simple list that has the potential to get lengthy. However to me it reads better.

**Route B**:

[image]

Can contain more times in the viewpoint (which is the clients preference) but it reads left to right which to me feels like a poorer experience.

I can't really find any research which would suggest which route, or if theres an industry standard.

My questions:

1. Is there a better way?
2. If not, what is the better way of the two above?

Comment: Are the appointment slots only 15 minutes long, or can I also book an appointment for say, half an hour or an hour? Also, if someone else has booked a given slot, I assume that slot would also become unavailable on the practitioner's calendar?

Comment: Slots are 15 minutes long only. And yes if the slot was booked it would become unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's room on mobile to have hour rows with 15-minute buttons. Hour rows are readable and scannable so users should be able to skip down to their hour.

[image]

Comment: Nice. Note that the gaps should be a little wider for accessibility. (I think Pagespeed and other tools would complain about the close targets.)

Comment: And if there isn't room to have five columns like that, then pivot it to have five rows and allow the table to scroll across to more hours.

Answer (score 2):

It should be just fine to have 2 entries per row. People tend to scan content with Z or F readings pattern, so they should be ok with consuming information like this. 
Another argument towards it could be that Calendly, worlds most used appointment management platform is having it also 2 per row.

 
Some things to bare in mind:

- You can potentially remove the radio button. Just with visual design (color change, maybe extra checkbox icon for selected state if you have it) you can clearly give user additional marks. Otherwise people could assume only radio button is tapable and not whole area
- It could make sense to have boxes same width
- If you will have very long list of time slots, additional filtering on top (i.e. Before vs After none) could help. Also if you have bottom action button this then could be sticky and overlayed
- If your geographical and other context allows it - you could have advantage of displaying hours in 24 instead of 12 format (16, 17, 18 instead of 4pm, 5pm, 6pm) as it will be easier to read for user

All in all, assuming you will have timeslots that will go beyond the height of your mobile viewport, you have advantage of showing 2 per row.

Comment: Hi @xul This seems to be more of a comment to the question, not an answer. You provided great answers in the past. Maybe you can add some more detail to this one too, for people who don't know Calendly (or to still provide valuable in case Calendly stops offering their product)?

Comment: @greenforest right, sorry, updated.

Comment: @xul That's a much improved answer.